# Existence of a Sequence Containing all Rationals

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

The following corollary was mentioned in my real analysis text.

**Corollary.** Let $(s_n)$ be any sequence with $\mathbb{Q} \subseteq \{ s_n \:|\: n \in \mathbb{N} \}$, and let $s \in \mathbb{R}$. Then there exists a subsequence of $(s_n)$ converging to $s$.

**Proof.** $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, so every (non-empty) open interval around $s$ contains infinitely many rationals. So, given an interval around $s$, there exist infinitely many $n$ with $s_n$ in that interval. So, $s$ is a limit of a subsequence of $(s_n)$.

Although I understand the logic behind the proof, I'm not sure what a sequence "containing all the rationals" is, and why it would exist. Does this have something to do with the nature of $\mathbb{Q}$ as countably infinite?

Comment: Yes, the claim that such a sequence exists is precisely the claim that $\mathbb{Q}$ is (at most) countable.

Comment: Presumably $\mathbb{Q} \in \{ s_n \:|\: n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ should read $\mathbb{Q} \subseteq \{ s_n \:|\: n \in \mathbb{N} \}$.

Comment: @RobArthan thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this depends on $\Bbb Q$ being countably infinite.  Because it is countably infinite, we can define a sequence $(t_n)$ that contains all and only the rationals.  We can explicitly define a subsequence $(u_n)$ of $(t_n)$ that converges to $s$.  First consider the interval $(s-1,s+1)$.  There are infinitely many elements of $t_n$ in that interval, so let $u_1$ be the first element of $t_n$ within the interval.  Then consider the interval $(s-\frac 12, s+\frac 12)$.  Again there are infinitely many rationals in the interval.  Let $u_2$ be the earliest element of $(t_n)$ that is after $u_1$ and within the interval.  Continue, with each interval being $(s-\frac 1k, s+\frac 1k)$ and taking the earliest element of $(t_n)$ after the previous element of $(u_n)$ and within the new interval.

This argument goes through if you sprinkle a bunch of irrationals among the rationals of $(t_n)$ to make $(s_n)$

Answer (score 0):

It has *everything* to do with $\mathbb Q$ being countable.

Countable means there is a 1-1 mapping $\phi:\mathbb N \rightarrow \mathbb Q$.

A sequence is nothing more than a mapping (not nesc. 1-1) from $\mathbb N$ onto a set.  i.e. $k \rightarrow a_k$ is a mapping where $f(k) = a_k$ which is nothing more or less than the the sequence $\{f(n)\}$.

So $\{a_n = \phi(n)\}= \mathbb Q$ is such a sequence.

====

Using the standard diagonal grid of the rationals argument that the rationals are countable, we can create such a sequence.   {1; 1/2, 2; 1/3,2/2,3;1/4,2/3,3/2,4;....}

Well actually that is only the non-negative positive rationals but the following will do it: {0,1,-1;1/2,-1/2,2,-2,1/3,-1/3,2/2,-2/2,3,-3,1/4,-1/4,2/3,-2/3,3/2,-3/2,4, -4,1/5,.....}

which clearly has a converging subsequence {1/2,1/3,1/4...} or if that was too obvious the converging {1/2,2/3,3/4,4/5,...}.  Or any other.